# Chapters and numbering in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

How do I create a numbering like this?
Since there is no number for `<header1>`, I'm not able to create this style at all.

```
Chapter 1: Introduction      <header1>

1.1 Intro                    <header2>
  1.1.1 Sub Intro            <header3>
1.2 XXX                      <header2>
1.3 YY                       <header2>

Chapter 2: Details           <header1>

2.1 Details1                 <header2>
2.2 More Details             <header2>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is better done as defining anew type of multilevel list (if you are having trouble finding it in Word 2013, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd><kbd>M</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.

Then, when you define the list style, you can set the level style (Link level to style), and the number of sections and the like to 1.1 and 1.1.1 etc. (Include level number from...)

[image]